# How to use filtered array in Azure pipeline template

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline template that takes an object type parameter as below:

MyTemplate.yml:

```
parameters:
  - name: repos
    type: object
    default:
        -name: Name1
         path: Path1
        -name: Name2
         path: Path2

steps:
    - bash: |
        names=(get list of names from repos)
        for name in names; do
           ...
        done
```

How do I implement that `(get list of names from repos)` logic so that the `names` shell variable can have value of "Name1 Name2" ?

The [Filtered Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#filtered-arrays) seems to be what I need but the document is not clear about how to use it. I tried `${{ parameters.repos.*.name }}` but pipeline complains `Unable to convert from Object to String. Value: Object`.

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters:
- name: myArray
  type: object
  default:
    - name: Name1
      path: Path1
    - name: Name2
      path: Path2


variables:
   A: ${{ join(';',parameters.myArray.*.name) }}

steps:
  - script: echo $A
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but I got `Unexpected value "variables"`. I guess `variables` are not allowed in step template.